# Measure intersection delay time

Tags: anylogic

Using the Road Traffic Library, I have created a 4-way intersection that is stop-controlled and I need to measure the average delay for each approach. Currently I am using timeMeasureStart and timeMeasureEnd blocks, showing the time taken as the car enters the road/model, until it exits the intersection.

Instead, I want to measure from the time the car slows to 40km/h, until it exits the intersection. Any suggestions?

The initial speed of all cars entering the model is 60 km/hr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Benjamin thank you for pointing me in the right direction.
Here is my solution, guided by the suggestion. I'm sure it could be refined but in the end it is what worked for me and my limited knowledge of AnyLogic.

For a 4-way intersection, I wanted the delay for each approach, so I created 4 custom car agents, with each populations starting out empty.
In each agent, I had 2 variable blocks - var_Start and var_Slow, an one event block set to Timeout, Cyclic, first read at time(), and proceeding in intervals of 0.1s. In the event action, i specidied the following:

```
if(getSpeed(KPH) <= 40) {
var_Slow=time();
var_Slow.suspend();
}
```

In main I used Histogram Data, labeled as dataDelay, and a chart with the mean showing, to see the results. I had one for each intersection.

Back in the car agent, in actions on startup:

```
var_Start=time();
```

and on destroy:

```
if(var_Slow = 0)
main.dataDelay.add(time()-var_Start);
else
main.dataDelay.add(time()-var_Slow);
```

At the car source block in main, I kept the initial and prefered speed at 60, however if there were cars backed up then new cars were often initiated at a slower speed, sometimes already below 40kph, hence the `if,else` code on destroy.

I had everything labeled according to its corresponding approach direction, unlike the simplified version I have here.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, there is no pre-defined way but this custom approach should work:

- make sure your cars are a custom agent type, not the default cars. Lets name it `My Car`
- add a variable `myTimeBelow40` into `MyCar` of type double
- check the car speed regularly (every 0.1 sec?!) in an event in `MyCar.checkSpeed`. Use the `getSpeed()` function. If it is below 40 KPH, you log the current time into `myTimeBelow40`
- log the departure time of your car: your time since 40 KPH is the difference

Finally, add a statistic across your car population or log your individual car duration into `main`

Comment: Great, thanks. I've created the custom car and provided it with the 'myTimeBelow40' parameter, but I'm a bit lost on how to go about the rest of what you've suggested.

Comment: Fair enough. Sounds like you should do a few more tutorials to learn about more advanced AnyLogic modelling. These are typical things many models need anyway so why not dig in now :)

Comment: Also @Kim , glad the answer was helpful to get you in the right direction. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)